# child transform does not move when moving the parent transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player controlled plattform. When moving to the outer edge, the platform starts to move. The width of the outer triggers are calculated by code.

So the player can move to any direction, he just needs to stay near the edge to trigger the movement.

[image: Platform TopDown View]

The player got a Rigidbody attached, the platform too. Here is an image of the inspector of platform I use

[image: Platform Inspector]

and this is the code attached

```
[SerializeField]
private float speed; // the movementSpeed

[SerializeField]
private float movementTriggerWidth; // width of the triggers at the outer edges

private Vector3 movementDirection = Vector3.zero;
private Rigidbody platformRigid;
private GameObject player;
private float triggerDistance; // distance from center to a trigger

private void Start()
{
    player = Globals.GetPlayerObject(); // search for the player Object in the scene
    platformRigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    triggerDistance = transform.localScale.x / 2 - movementTriggerWidth; // set the trigger distance
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    col.transform.parent = transform; // set the player as a child of the platform
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
{
    col.transform.parent = null; // leave the platform
}

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject == player) // only the player can move the platform
    {
        Vector3 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
        Vector3 platformPosition = transform.position;

        if (Vector3.Distance(playerPosition, platformPosition) > triggerDistance) // player is in outer trigger?
        {
            movementDirection = playerPosition - platformPosition; // calculate the movement direction
            platformRigid.MovePosition(transform.position + movementDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime); // move the platform
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem:

When jumping on a platform, the player becomes a child of the platform. But when the platform starts moving the player is not affected by this. He doesn't get moved by the platform.

I hope someone can help me solving this "little" ( ? ) bug.

Update:

Here is a picture of the player inspector

[image: PlayerInspector]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html - this might help

Comment: ahh ok, so my platforms have to be not kinematic. But when jumping on a non kinematic platform, it just falls down. Even if "use gravity" deactivated.

Comment: Can you share the image of the player inspector too?

Comment: @ZayedUpal I updated my post but as Fiffe mentioned above, I need to switch the kinematic state.

Comment: So how can I achieve a kinematic behaviour without having it on a kinematic state?

Comment: @Question3r making the platform's isKinematic to true and Use gravity to false worked for me. Make sure, the code enters in OnTriggerStay for the player.

Comment: The player is not affected by the platform movement. Fiffe posted a link, there you can see the kinematic state disables collisions.

Comment: Here's my result: https://imgur.com/a/xfWI2

Comment: Just use Freeze position Y

Answer (score 0):

Well I went for some tries and this is a working solution for me.

**I removed the rigidbody**

and took this code

```
[SerializeField]
private float speed;

[SerializeField]
private float movementTriggerWidth;

private Vector3 movementDirection;
private bool move = false;
private GameObject player;
private float triggerDistance;

private void Start()
{
    player = Globals.GetPlayerObject();
    triggerDistance = transform.localScale.x / 2 - movementTriggerWidth;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    col.transform.parent = transform;
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
{
    col.transform.parent = null;
}

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject == player)
    {
        Vector3 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
        Vector3 platformPosition = transform.position;

        if (Vector3.Distance(playerPosition, platformPosition) > triggerDistance)
        {
            movementDirection = playerPosition - platformPosition;
            move = true;
        }
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (move)
        transform.Translate(movementDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    move = false;
}
```

Now the platform is moved by `Translate()` in the `FixedUpdate()`. `OnTriggerStay()` just checks, if the platform should be moved or not.